# Android: Bitmap uploaded via HttpURLConnection not usable

Tags: android, bitmap, upload, format, corrupt

I am using an Android app to upload an image taken with the camera. The camera returns the bitmap, which is passed to the upload task. The server receives the image and saves it, but it appears to be formatted incorrectly; I can not view the image. Is there something I am missing about the Android `Bitmap.compress()` function? I'm not familiar with image formatting so any help wuld really be appreciated.

Here is the code where the bitmap is written:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("imageToUpload", "ups.jpg");
String sUserID = Integer.toString(mUserID);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

os.write((dbHyphen + boundary + lnEnd).getBytes());
os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"p\"" + lnEnd).getBytes());
os.write(("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"+ lnEnd).getBytes());
os.write(lnEnd.getBytes());
os.write(sUserID.getBytes());os.write(lnEnd.getBytes());
os.write(lnEnd.getBytes());
os.write((dbHyphen + boundary + lnEnd).getBytes());
os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageToUpload\";filename="
        + "ups.jpg" + lnEnd).getBytes());
os.write((lnEnd).getBytes());

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

os.write(bitmapdata);
os.write((lnEnd).getBytes());
os.write((dbHyphen + boundary + dbHyphen + lnEnd).getBytes());
os.close();
```

EDIT: The upload it received and save via php

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name'], $file_path))
```

Comment: What kind of server? Do you blame the server or your Android code?

Comment: How many bytes in the file which you upload? How many in the saved one?

Comment: It is uploaded to a web server and processed via php. The buffer the bitmap is written to reads byte[4505]@3894 in the debugger (need to lookup the meaning of that syntax). The file once copied to my local drive is reading 4,882 bytes. It never gets saved as an actual file on the android.

Comment: Why isnt there a content type image/jpeg at the second form data? Look in the saved file to see the differences.

Comment: I tried adding, without luck: os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\";name="+ "ups.jpg" + lnEnd).getBytes());
                os.write(("Content-Type: image/jpeg"+ lnEnd).getBytes());
                os.write(("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"  + lnEnd).getBytes());

Comment: Thanks for the responses greenapps, figured it out and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. The image data stream still needs to be formatted into a jpeg file. The php on the site needed to be modified.

Here is the php snippet to convert the data into an image and save it.

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']);

$imageFile = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$imageName = "test.jpeg";
$imageSave = imagejpeg($imageFile,$imageName,100);
imagedestroy($imageFile);
```

And the revised code for the Android:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("imageToUpload", "ups.jpg");
            String sUserID = Integer.toString(mUserID);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            os.write((dbHyphen + boundary + lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"p\"" + lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write(("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"+ lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write(lnEnd.getBytes());
            os.write(sUserID.getBytes());os.write(lnEnd.getBytes());
            os.write(lnEnd.getBytes());
            os.write((dbHyphen + boundary + lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageToUpload\";filename="+ "ups.jpg" + lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write(("Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8"+ lnEnd).getBytes());//"+ lnEnd).getBytes());
            //os.write(("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"  + lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write((lnEnd).getBytes());

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
            int lng = bitmapdata.length;
            os.write(bitmapdata);
            os.write((lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.write((dbHyphen + boundary + dbHyphen + lnEnd).getBytes());
            os.close();
```